# Laravel, ligação entre o back office e o front office

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Boa Tarde, 
estou a fazer um pequeno projeto com Back office e Front office em Laravel. No back office são criados todos os dados que são depois apresentados no front office, ou seja, as noticias que os utilizadores poderam consultar são criadas no back office e depois inseridas num layout especifico. 
Não estou a conseguir perceber como é que posso enviar as noticias para o layout, será que alguém me pode explicar?

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples, contando que você tenha no seu layout a instrução para imprimir uma view:
`@yield('content')`, no final do método do seu controller você simplesmente retorna:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NoticiasController extends Controller
{
    public function noticias()
    {
        $noticias = [];//aqui você retorna as noticias do model
        return view('noticias', compact('noticias'));
    }
}
```